# How to access remotely the Dotnetnuke web server

Tags: dotnetnuke, remote-access

I am a freelancer and right now I am working in Dotnetnuke project. 
I've given with some IP address of DNN staging server(say: 10.x.x.x) with username and password for remote access ...

I could not make use of this credentials and I studied all aspects.
Can I know where and how I should use this IP credentials ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The credentials you were given will more than likely fall into one of four categories:

1. **Remote Desktop account**

   You'll use the Remote Desktop Connection/Client program on your Windows machine to connect to the staging server.  You'll enter the IP address, user name, and password, and you'll be given a remote session into the Windows server environment.
2. **FTP account**

   You'll use an FTP program (I use Filezilla) to gain access to the file system on the staging server.  You'll enter the IP address, user name, and password, and you'll see the folder structure of the DNN website.
3. **Web-based file system account**

   You'll open a web browser and navigate to some URL (perhaps GoDaddy or another web host), enter the user name and password, and you'll be given access to numerous web hosting abilities, like navigating the file system and managing the database.
4. **DNN admin/host account**

   You'll open the staging website in your web browser by going to the IP address you were given, click the Login link, enter the user name and password, and you'll be able to edit the DNN content.

Having said all this, the best course of action is to simply ask whoever provided you the credentials what means of remote access they're meant to be used with.

Comment: thanks Tim .. but I was also given some links on sharepoint DNN access ... Neither that too didn't work..